# Should we point to an NSManagedObject entity with weak instead of strong pointer?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmanagedobject

I think because NSManagedObject is managed by the managedObject context the pointer should be weak.

Yet it often goes back to 0 in my cases.

```
    for (CategoryNearby * CN in sorted) {
        //[arrayOfItems addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %d",CN.name,[CN.order intValue]]];
        NearbyShortcutTVC * tvc=[[NearbyShortcutTVC alloc]init];
        tvc.categoryNearby =CN;
//        tvc.titleString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",CN.name];
//        tvc.displayed=CN.displayed;
        [arrayOfItemsLocal addObject:tvc];
        //CN

        PO(tvc);
        PO(tvc.categoryNearby);
        while (false);
    }
    self.arrayOfItems = arrayOfItemsLocal;

    PO(self.categoriesNearbyInArrayOfItems);
    [self.tableViewa reloadData];
```

...

Yet somewhere down the line:

`tvc.categoryNearby` becomes nil.

I do not know how or when or where it become nil.

How do I debug this? Or should the reference be strong instead?

This is the interface of NearbyShortcutTVC by the way

```
@interface NearbyShortcutTVC : BGBaseTableViewCell{

}
@property (weak, nonatomic) CategoryNearby * categoryNearby;

@end
```

To make sure that we're talking about the same object I print all the memory addresses of the NSArray

They're both the exact same object. But somehow the categoryNearby property of the object is magically set to null somewhere.

```
 self.categoriesNearbyInArrayOfItems: (
    0x883bfe0,
    0x8b6d420,
    0x8b6f9f0,
    0x8b71de0,
    0xb073f90,
    0xb061a10,
    0xb06a880,
    0x8b74940,
    0x8b77110,
    0x8b794e0,
    0x8b7bf40,
    0x8b7cef0,
    0x8b7f4b0,
    0x8b81a30,
    0x88622d0,
    0x8864e60,
    0xb05c9a0
)

self.categoriesNearbyInArrayOfItems: (
    0x883bfe0,
    0x8b6d420,
    0x8b6f9f0,
    0x8b71de0,
    0xb073f90,
    0xb061a10,
    0xb06a880,
    0x8b74940,
    0x8b77110,
    0x8b794e0,
    0x8b7bf40,
    0x8b7cef0,
    0x8b7f4b0,
    0x8b81a30,
    0x88622d0,
    0x8864e60,
    0xb05c9a0
)
```

I modified my debugging function to print the TVC object and it's categoryNearby property

the categoryNearby property is set to nil

However, if I make the reference strong it's not nil anymore

```
-(NSArray *) categoriesNearbyInArrayOfItems
{
    NSMutableArray *categoriesArray = [NSMutableArray array];


    for (NearbyShortcutTVC * tvc in self.arrayOfItems) {
        NSString * string  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%p,%p",tvc,tvc.categoryNearby];
        [categoriesArray addObject:string];
    }
    return categoriesArray;
}
```

Result in:

```
2012-11-06 12:01:00.878 BadgerNew[66443:c07] self.categoriesNearbyInArrayOfItems: (
    "0x8dc96b0,0x88a58b0",
    "0x8bde780,0x88b7970",
    "0x8be0930,0x88b8870",
    "0x8bf1c00,0x88b8ca0",
    "0x8bf4070,0x8beab10",
    "0x8bf6250,0x8beaf10",
    "0x8bf8620,0x8beb390",
    "0x8bfae90,0x8beb7b0",
    "0x8b707e0,0x8bebbd0",
    "0x8b6e160,0x8bebfe0",
    "0x8b6ba10,0x8bec450",
    "0x8b69a60,0x8bec870",
    "0x8b673a0,0x8becc90",
    "0x8b648c0,0x8bed0a0",
    "0x8b62110,0x8b7dca0",
    "0x8b5f890,0x8bedbe0",
    "0xd678410,0x8bee0e0"
)
2012-11-06 12:01:10.058 BadgerNew[66443:4503] Interval for this Grab ID is 9.232143
2012-11-06 12:01:10.058 BadgerNew[66443:4503] @(data.count): 20
2012-11-06 12:01:10.414 BadgerNew[66443:c07] self.categoriesNearbyInArrayOfItems: (
    "0x8dc96b0,0x88a58b0",
    "0x8bde780,0x88b7970",
    "0x8be0930,0x88b8870",
    "0x8bf1c00,0x88b8ca0",
    "0x8bf4070,0x8beab10",
    "0x8bf6250,0x8beaf10",
    "0x8bf8620,0x8beb390",
    "0x8bfae90,0x8beb7b0",
    "0x8b707e0,0x8bebbd0",
    "0x8b6e160,0x8bebfe0",
    "0x8b6ba10,0x8bec450",
    "0x8b69a60,0x8bec870",
    "0x8b673a0,0x8becc90",
    "0x8b648c0,0x8bed0a0",
    "0x8b62110,0x8b7dca0",
    "0x8b5f890,0x8bedbe0",
    "0xd678410,0x8bee0e0"
)
```

While the problem is solved, it's still strange. That categoryNearby should not be nilled even if the reference is weak. It's a subclass of NSManagedObject that's directly managed by the managed object context. Also the fact that I can still access it when the reference is strong shows that the object is still in memory.

So how come it becomes nil?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want an `NSManagedObject` to stay around, you need to keep a strong reference to it (or put it in a container that strongly holds its contents).  The managed object context **does not** keep strong references to all of the objects associated with it.

“The Role of the Managed Object Context” in the [*Core Data Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMemory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001860-SW5) says this:

> *By default*, though, the references between a managed object and its context are weak. This means that in general you cannot rely on a context to ensure the longevity of a managed object instance, and you cannot rely on the existence of a managed object to ensure the longevity of a context. Put another way, just because you fetched an object doesn’t mean it will stay around.

It goes on to explain the times when the context *does* strongly retain objects, and how you can change the context to always strongly retain objects, and how you should make sure the objects you need are not deallocated.

Comment: Interesting. In other parts of the code, I used weak reference just fine. I guess in those code something else keep it from being deallocated.

Comment: rob, how to solve this then ? should i set setRetainsRegisteredObjects as yes so that the references stay longer ?

Comment: would also be interested to know